# Partition edges of a graph with NetworkX and Python

Tags: python, networkx, partition

I would like to partition edges of a graph `g` based on edge attributes, using Python and NetworkX. In this snippet:

```
import networkx as nx

g = nx.Graph()
g.add_node(1, pos=[0, 0])
g.add_node(2, pos=[0, 2])
g.add_node(3, pos=[1, 1])
g.add_node(4, pos=[2, 1])
g.add_edge(1, 3, cat='a')
g.add_edge(4, 3, cat='a')
g.add_edge(1, 2, cat='b')
g.add_edge(4, 2, cat='b')
```

I would like to partition graph `g` into graphs `ga` and `gb` based on `cat` attribute and retain node attribute `pos`. Note that nodes `1` and `4` will belong to both `ga` and `gb`. Is there a library support for this operation?

Answer (score 2):

you could use a combination of list comprehension and sets:

```
ga = g.subgraph(set(*[[u,v] for (u,v,data) in g.edges(data=True) if data.get('cat')=='a']))
gb = g.subgraph(set(*[[u,v] for (u,v,data) in g.edges(data=True) if data.get('cat')=='b']))
```

Comment: Your solution produces sets, but I was looking for graphs. I edited the question to make this more clear.

Comment: @PaulJurczak see my edit, using `g.subgraph`

Comment: Your solution fails in case of more than one edge in the subgraph. I edited my question to make my example more general.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a simple solution:

```
ga = g.edge_subgraph(e for e in g.edges() if g.edges[e]['cat']=='a')
gb = g.edge_subgraph(e for e in g.edges() if g.edges[e]['cat']=='b')
```